# Angular can't return json content to object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get a json file content to an object

```
var myApp = angular.module('AngularPortfolio', []);

myApp.config( function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.projects = {};
    $http.get('../bundles/xxxxxxxxxx/portfolio/data.json')
    .success( function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
    })
    .error( function(data) {
        console.log('ERREUR');
    });
}]);
```

(edit latest post)
My JSON file :

```
[
    {
        "title": "example 01",
        "img" : "1.jpg",
        "filters" : {
            "accompagner" : "communication corporate",
            "solutions" : "digital"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "example 02",
        "img" : "2.jpg",
        "filters" : {
            "accompagner" : "communication financiere",
            "solutions" : "strategies et dispositifs"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "example 03",
        "img" : "3.jpg",
        "filters" : {
            "accompagner" : "communication rse et developpement durable",
            "solutions" : "design et identite"
        }
    }
]
```

(edit latest post) And my ng-repeat code :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in projects">
          <img src="../bundles/xxxxxxxx/uploads/{[{item.img}]}" alt="{[{item.title}]}">
          <h3>{[{item.title}]}</h3>
        </div>
```

This code return data like a string and I cannot use this to a ng-repeat.
Can you help me ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your data.json?

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)` to create an array/object from json string

Comment: I just have to edit my Question :)

Comment: I can't use JSON.parse() I have already test this issue but Angular return an error

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, my JSON file is valid

Comment: Nevermind angular automatically parses json data

Comment: show your ng-repeat code

Comment: So why my data variable is returned as a string ?

Comment: and why you need     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
 ??

Comment: $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}'); it's because I use this code in a twig file

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your shared `JSON` file it would be like this, if it's your final `JSON` output, if not please share your final `JSON` which you are getting in controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in projects track by $index">
          <img ng-src="../bundles/xxxxxxxx/uploads/{{item.img}}" alt="{{item.title}}">
          <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: the shared JSON file is my finnaly (for test) file

Comment: you getting the same in the controller ?

Comment: yep a console.log(data) return the same

Comment: YEs, I have the same error Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: item in projects key: string: 
Because my data variable is returned as a string